# AngularJS with jquery contradict with each other

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I followed this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nz8lAKHBgJY
to be able  to use sevensegment.js jquery plug with angular. 
the first step was to include jquery before angular even before starting to integrate knob( as the example in the video). 
but the angular is already does not work. 
when i added jquery (> 2.1) with angular ? 1.3 i got the expression code instead of the data

```
<script src="js/Angular/angular.js"></script>
<!--<script src="js/Angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-router-ui/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
```

Example:
cdata.StartMeasure}}    {{cdata.StoppedMeasure}}

my target is to use sevensegment.js with angular and i think the way to do it is to build a directive for it like David showing in the video , but i am already failed with the first step. 
if i remove jquery my angular code working fine ( working under Node.js)

Thank you.

Comment: As it is said in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background) accepted answer, if you use AngularJS, you shouldn't use jQuery at all. I don't know whether it is absolutely correct idea, but it is definitely worth to think about it.

Comment: Oh my goodness. You can CERTAINLY use jQuery with AngularJS. In fact, you need to do so in order to build a directive around an existing jQuery plugin, as in my video. Without jQuery, Angular 1.x uses jqLite, a lightweight jQuery substitute. With jQuery, Angular just gets more powerful. What you should NOT do is do direct jQuery DOM manipulation in an Angular controller.  Now, on this question, it's still not clear what's happening. Try setting up a jsFiddle to show what's happening and add that to your question.